# building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for macOS, for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, static-libraries, ld, mac-catalyst

In `Xcode`, my `Catalyst` project's build fails with error like:

```
ld: in /build-dir/libBackend.a(my-file.cpp.o), 
building for Mac Catalyst, 
but linking in object file built for macOS, 
for architecture x86_64
```

**How can I fix above?**
(and what does it even mean).

> **Note** that `libBackend.a` is my static-library linked into my App (and `my-file.cpp` represents some file inside that library).

Answer (score 0):

If you allow, here is how I fixed it; but first, the log's meaning:

The "`building for Mac Catalyst`" part was confusing, because it is written after mentioning `libBackend.a` file.

Message sounds like "`your library is built for Catalyst but my-file.cpp.o is built for macOS`".
But it actually means:

- You are trying to build for Catalyst,
- but your whole library, or at least the `my-file.cpp.o` object file,
- Was built for macOS (without targeting Catalyst).

### Solution:

The fix was to ensure the right flag really gets passed to `clang`-compiler !!
I mean, although "`-target x86_64-apple-ios13.6-macabi`" was in my flags,
due to a mistake, the target-flag was never reaching the compiler.

### Testing:

If below causes compile-error (no matter if C, C++, Obj-C), then you have the same issue.

```cpp
#ifdef __APPLE__
#   include <TargetConditionals.h>
#   if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
#       error "Unsupported platform!"
#   endif
#endif
```

### Background:

I was implementing [`CMake` support for `Xcode` on Github](https://github.com/top-master/xcode-cmake-support),
which supports `iOS`, Mac's `Catalyst` and maybe `tvOS` and `watchOS`
(because even in 2021, `CMake` still does not have built-in support).